# Can I use a font from Google Font and edit it in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, font-licensing

I have to make a logo for a customer and I would like to use a font from Google Font, but can I edit it on illustrator? I have seen that Google Fonts are also free for commercial use, but are they editable? I’m talking about convert the text to a vector outline and change some anchor points.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a license grants you commercial use, then **yes** you can create outlines and edit the glyphs in whatever manner you wish, unless otherwise stated in the license.

*Most* commercial licenses merely restrict the *distribution* or *sharing* of the actual font files themselves, not usage for the license holder.

<sup>(Note I used "most" because it's not impossible for a commercial license to restrict usage. I've simply never seen such a restriction myself.)</sup>

Comment: Mainly because such use would not work in USA